# Regex does not apply to whole string

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

the following regex

```
var str = "1234,john smith,jack jone";
var match = str.match(/([^,]*,[^,]*,[^ ]*)/g);
alert(match);
```

returns

```
1234,john smith,jack
```

But what I am trying to get is the whole string which is

```
1234,john smith,jack jones
```

Basically my script does the job only for the first whitespace between commas but I want to do it everytime there is a white space between commas.

Can anyone help me out pls.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your pattern excludes spaces from the last section so as soon as it encounters a space in after the third comma, that's the end of the match. You might want to try this instead:

```
var match = str.match(/[^,]*,[^,]*,.*/g);
```

This will allow anything after the second comma, including spaces or more commas (since your original pattern allowed commas after the the second).

If you'd like to match pattern only on a single, use start / end anchors (`^` / `$`) as well as the multiline flag (`m`), like us this:

```
var match = str.match(/^[^,]*,[^,]*,.*$/mg);
```

You can try it out with [this simple demo](http://jsfiddle.net/TCMcp/).

Comment: Also the capture group is unnecessary, and `match` doesn't capture groups in global regex anyway...

Comment: @elclanrs Good point. Although I have a feeling OP included the `g` flag in an attempt to capture the last part of the string. It's not necessary even if the `g` is removed because the entire match was surrounded by the capture group. You can just as easily get the whole match as you can a group.

Comment: @p.s.w.g thnx for the reply, can you please let me know a way to make this regex not sensitive on new line? currently when I have more than one entry (in more than one line), the check takes it as an space and mix up all lines!

Comment: @p.s.w.g cheers for the answer. When I try your example it works fine. But in my case, I am pasting (.on(paste, ...) ) similar lines to my field (to validate lines one by one) it takes the whole content as one entry (still does not differ new line from space I guess!). any idea why?

Comment: @ComeRun Can you reproduce the issue in a jsFiddle?

Comment: @p.s.w.g please have a look http://jsfiddle.net/TCMcp/1/ as you can see it alerts the whole string in one piece!

Comment: @ComeRun I see the issue now. Simple text inputs do not support multi-line text, so evidently it's flattening it to a single line before calling your event handler. If you replace it with a `textarea` it works as expected--[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/TCMcp/2/). I don't think there's any way to do this with a simple input, but you may be able to tweak a text area so that it *looks* like a simple input. This behavior may not be entirely consistent among browsers, either, so I'd recommend thorough testing.

Answer (score 0):

Why you're not using split ?

```
"1234,john smith,jack jone".split(/,/)
```

or

```
"1234,john smith,jack jone".split(",")
```